# SQL Server: Maximum number of constraints referencing a table

Tags: sql-server

In our database, there are about 1000 tables referencing table: FAMILIES. When we try to delete a record from FAMILIES, we're seeing below error:

Msg 8621, Level 17, State 1, Line 81
The query processor ran out of stack space during query optimization. Please simplify the query.

I noticed we can reproduce this issue if a table has more than 918 foreign constraints referencing to the table. Below is the code to reproduce the error.

Below code: 
    Creates table FAMILIES
    Insert sample records
    Create tables referencing FAMILIES (@tbl_count is number of tables to be created)
    Delete record from FAMILIES

If we change value of @tbl_count to 918 or less, the code works fine.

1. What is the maximum number of any constraints (or foreign key reference) a table can have?
2. If there are more than 1000 tables referencing a table, is there a way to address the error?

This issue is reproducible in SQL Server 2012 and 2014, but works fine in 2016. 
I'm working on Windows10.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
  CREATE TABLE families (fmly_key BIGINT, PRIMARY KEY (fmly_key))
  INSERT INTO families VALUES (10)

  DECLARE @v_count BIGINT = 0, @sql_stmt NVARCHAR(MAX), @tbl_count BIGINT = 919

  WHILE @v_count < @tbl_count
  BEGIN
    SET @v_count = @v_count + 1
    SET @sql_stmt = 'CREATE TABLE TABLE'+cast(@v_count as nvarchar(max))+' (COL1 BIGINT, FOREIGN KEY (COL1) REFERENCES FAMILIES (FMLY_KEY))'
    exec sp_executesql @sql_stmt  
  END

  DELETE FROM families WHERE fmly_key = 10
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The supported limits were rased in SQL 2016.  See

> the actual number of FOREIGN KEY constraints that can be
>   used is limited by the hardware configuration and by the design of the
>   database and application. We recommend that a table contain no more
>   than 253 FOREIGN KEY constraints, and that it be referenced by no more
>   than 253 FOREIGN KEY constraints.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-foreign-key-relationships?view=sql-server-2014

> SQL Server 2016 (13.x) increases the limit for the number of other
>   table and columns that can reference columns in a single table
>   (incoming references), from 253 to 10,000.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-foreign-key-relationships?view=sql-server-2016